# ranking data using vba

Tags: vba, excel

i come to ask your help i need to rank data using vba i have a block of results in column D and i want to rank them in column E without skiping any value so i tried this vba code but it gives me only zeros in all the column then my computer becom slow untill i close the excel file  this is the vba code i am using if anyone can help me :

```
Sub Mactro5()
LastRow = Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2:E" & LastRow).Formula = _
    "=IF(D2=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",SUMPRODUCT((D$2:D$" & LastRow & ">D2)/COUNTIF(D$2:D$" & LastRow & ",D$2:D$" & LastRow & "&" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "))+1)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel has got [RANK](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723) function. Use it.

Comment: Do you want the **highest** value to have a rank **1** or the **lowest**  ??

Comment: i know but excel skips values like if two cells have the same value he will give them the same rank like 7 7 the he will passe to 9  thats whey i dont want to use the rank formula of excel

Comment: @Gary'sStudent yes  in deed the highest value will have one then it goes ... but without skiping values

Comment: What is the tiebreaker for 2 values that are the same?

Comment: @Histerical i dont understand what you mean ??

Comment: If there are 2 values that are the same, you said you don't want them to have the same rank, so how are they ranked, is there something else that is decided upon if the ranks are the same?

Comment: no no it is the opposite if 2 values are the same i want them to have the same value like 1 1 1 but the seconde value normally the excel function will put itt on 4  , i want it to be ranked 2